# Check if Observable in debounceTime() progress

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, subject

How can I execute `.next()` on `Subject` only if it is in debouncing progress?

```
let someFlag = true;
if (someFlag) {
    someFlag = false;
        if (this.resizeDebouncer !== null)) {
            this.resizeDebouncer = new Subject<Event>();
            this.resizeDebouncer.pipe(
                debounceTime(1000)
            ).subscribe(e => console.log(e.type));
        }

    }
this.resizeDebouncer.next(event); // should be executed only if resizeDebouncer subject in debouncing progress. 
// Don't execute if nothing is running
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any marker for debouncing in progress. Neither `.isClosed` nor `.isStopped` doesn't fit. But I've solved my issue by unsubscribing from `Subject` each time inside subscription. In this case subscription exists only in range of debouncing progress and in other time `.next()` doesn't do anything.

```
let subscription = this.resizeDebouncer
    .pipe(debounceTime(300))
    .subscribe(e => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        e => console.log(e.type);
    });
```